# PHP template for messaging system

Tags: php, database

I am currently working on a system will send messages to a number of people/machines. I will not go through the details, only with the relevant parts.

There are a number of details to be sent, like:

- employee name
- number of hours worked
- salary
- etc

These values are fetched from a database, however, the sender is allowed to format the message however he likes. For example, he can do:

```
"Good day <employee name>, you'll earn <salary> on <date>
```

or

```
"Hello, your salary has been increased by <amount>. 
Your current salary is: <salary>
```

wherein the values from the database will be substituted on the tags. What is the best way to do these kinds of templates?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to find template engine that suites your needs, but, as far as I know, there is no engine which uses yours variable notation ( `< var >`), so I think you'll have to write your own bicycle.

Also you may change your variable notation to, for example, TWIG (`{{ var }}`) and use it as a ready solution, but all your senders must use this notation to write their messages

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `str_replace`-function for simple replacements in a string:

```
$template = "Good day <employee name>, you'll earn <salary> on <date>";

$vars = array();
$vars[0] = '<employee name>';
$vars[1] = '<salary>';
$vars[2] = '<date>';

$values = array();
$values[0] = 'Peter Parker';
$values[1] = '450 &euro;';
$values[2] = '01.01.2015';

str_replace( $vars, $values, $template );
```

[php: str_replace - Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)